# add keyDown event to canvas in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, html5-canvas

I am trying to upload a game to itch.io, but I coded all the input my self and the key press events won't work when I upload the game.

The html that matters  is

```
<iframe>
    #document
    <canvas id="canvasId">
</iframe
```

My javascript that isn't working is

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasId");    
canvas.addEventListener("keydown",kdown);
```

This is itch.io, so I can't have any code outside the iframe.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a good solution, but doing `window.focus();` when ever the canvas is clicked makes the keys work.